# Not able to inject Person service as autowired

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I'm trying to use person service as part of spring application.

Here is my code

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person_data")
class Person {

@Id
    @Column(
    columnDefinition = "NUMERIC(19,0)"
)
private Long id;
private String first_name;
private String last_name;

public String getFullName() {
    return new StringBuilder().append(first_name).append(last_name).toString();
}
}

@Service
class PersonService {

@Autowired 
PersonRepository repository;

List<Person> findAll() {
    return (List<Person>) repository.findAll();
}

}


@Repository
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {}
```

When I build the above the code, I'm getting the following exception

```
 ERROR] /task/src/main/java/com/codility/tasks/hibernate/solution/Solution.java:[36,6] can  
 not find symbol
 symbol:   class Autowired
 location: class com.codility.tasks.hibernate.solution.PersonService
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.451 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-09T06:40:46Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile 
   (default-compile) on project hibernate-one-to-many-task: 
Compilation failure
[ERROR]
```

Why is it not able to autowire

Comment: it looks like you forgot to add proper import - didn't you?

Comment: Yes, you are right @m.antkowicz

Answer (score 0):

Import statement was missing. Thank you all.